# Cálculo de SLA en BD

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

quisiera consultar como realizarían el **calculo de un SLA en una bd**.

Se debe considerar que esta base de datos tiene 1 tabla que almacena un id, fecha de inicio y fecha de termino, por ende, el calculo se debiese hacer referente a estas 2 fechas indicadas, ademas, existe otra tabla que almacena los feriados.

La idea es que el calculo sea en el resultado de la fecha de fin - la fecha de inicio y sin contar el horario inhábil (suponiendo que las jornadas laborales sean de 08:00 hasta las 18:00).

> ***Ejemplo del calculo:***
>
> Fecha de inicio: 14/08/2019 08:00
>
> Fecha de termino: 16/08/2019 18:00
>
> Día 15/08/2019 es feriado
>
> Por ende el *total de las horas debiese ser 20.* (esto ya que solo se contó el horario hábil y se descontó el día feriado).

**¿que recomiendan para realizar este calculo?**, he investigado varias alternativas pero con ninguna llego al resultado final que necesito.

Cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida!

Comment: puedes explicar que es un `SLA`?  no creo que el calculo de la superficie de impresion en resina sea posible con fechas de inicio y fin... :)

Comment: SLA es un Acuerdos de nivel de servicio, ahí se pueden definir cuanto es el tiempo que se debe demorar x servicio en responder, ejemplo, cuantas horas se debería demorar un técnico en reparar un equipo.

Comment: muy interesante y de mucha utilidad tu pregunta, estuve probando con `timestampdiff` pero no logro filtrar las hs inhábiles

Comment: parece ser que es muy dificil hacerlo con base de datos, si no habría que crear un método con el programa, pero no sé si estás usando esa base con un programa. Yo solo se java, si queres te lo programo

Comment: Que alternativas has mirado? Así de primeras puedes hacer la resta de días entre fecha inicio y fecha termino. Ese resultado lo multiplicas por 10. Luego buscas en la tabla de feriados el número de días que hay entre las dos fechas. Lo multiplicas por 10. El resultado que buscas es la resta del primer valor y del segundo. Creo que hasta lo puedes hacer en una única consulta con su consulta..

Comment: @JuanRom si deseas puedes hacerlo en java, así tenemos una idea de como se podría hacer. Igual se podria hacer varias consultas y almacenarlas en alguna funcion.

Comment: @Jakala creo que la que mas he visto y podría resultar, es realizar un ciclo que considere la fecha de inicio y la de fin, que descarte los feriados. Tenia pensado que cada vez que realice el ciclo evalué que día de la semana es y que en un contador de horas, almacene la cantidad de hora totales, osea, dependiendo el día sume x cantidad de horas. Hasta el momento he visto esa opción y ya logre que evaluara que día es, sólo me faltaría ver como hacer el ciclo que comience desde el día de inicio y termine en la fecha fin, y como excluir los feriados.

Comment: hola, probaste alguna de las respuestas que te sugerimos? Contanos como te fue

Answer (score 0):

Añado una respuesta, a partir de ciertas ideas mias:

Lo primero, he creado las dos tablas que indicas y he insertado registros:

```
CREATE TABLE sla
( id INT NOT NULL,
  inicio DATETIME,
  fin DATETIME
);

insert into sla(id, inicio, fin) VALUES 
 (1, "2019/08/14 08:00", "2019/08/16 18:00"),
 (2, "2019/08/19 08:00", "2019/08/22 18:00"),
 (3, "2019/08/25 08:00", "2019/08/26 18:00"),
 (4, "2019/08/01 08:00", "2019/08/10 18:00");

CREATE TABLE feriados
(
 ferias DATETIME NOT NULL
);

insert into feriados(ferias) VALUES
 ("2019/08/15"),
 ("2019/08/21"),
 ("2019/08/06"),
 ("2019/08/16");
```

despues de investigar por ahi, he llegado a esta sql, que ayuda a obtener la informacion que necesitas (basandonos en las tablas anteriores):

```
select id, inicio, fin , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, inicio, fin)+1 as TRABAJADOS, count(ferias) as FERIAS 
FROM sla, feriados 
WHERE ferias BETWEEN inicio AND fin 
GROUP BY id, inicio, fin
```

Utilizo TIMESTAMPDIFF para calcular la diferencia entre las fechas. Le sumo 1 (porque hay que contar tambien el primer dia). El FROM es un producto cartesiano (no utilizamos join, porque el where va a filtrar los datos por ferias que esten entre las fechas. Por ultimo, el grupo de GROUP BY es para el count(ferias).

Esta consulta nos da un resultado como el siguiente:

```
ID       INICIO             FIN             TRABAJADOS   FERIAS
1   2019-08-14 08:00:00 2019-08-16 18:00:00     3          2
2   2019-08-19 08:00:00 2019-08-22 18:00:00     4          1
4   2019-08-01 08:00:00 2019-08-10 18:00:00     10         1
```

En el caso de la linea 1, se trabajan 3 dias (14,15 y 16) y hay dos ferias (15 y 16). Son dos dias porque he puesto esos dos en la tabla feriados.

Se podria ir un poco mas alla con la sql, como:

```
SELECT id, inicio, fin , (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, inicio, fin)+1 - count(ferias)) * 10 as HORAS_TRABAJADAS
FROM sla, feriados 
WHERE ferias BETWEEN inicio AND fin 
GROUP BY id, inicio, fin
```

Y obtienes una salida como la siguiente:

```
ID          INICIO              FIN              HORAS_TRABAJADAS
1   2019-08-14 08:00:00 2019-08-16 18:00:00          10
2   2019-08-19 08:00:00 2019-08-22 18:00:00          30
4   2019-08-01 08:00:00 2019-08-10 18:00:00          90
```

El resultado que buscas lo tienes directo desde la SQL. Solo te resta iterar los resultados con el lenguaje que prefieras.

**NOTA:** te he dejado las dos SQL porque es muy posible que en un futuro cambies las horas de trabajo, o que las de ferias tengas que contarlas doble... en ese caso te interesara mas la primera, e ir iterando para multiplicar por las horas de trabajo y las horas de ferias (y luego restar). Eso se hace mas facilmente a traves de un bucle, en lugar de cambiar la sql.

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar mucho, llegué a la conclusión que la mejor forma, y no sé si la única, de hacer esto es mediante un **procedimiento almacenado**, ya que es muy complejo lo que pedís. Un procedimiento almacenado te permite crear variables, bucles, y todo lo necesario como si estuvieras programando en un lenguaje como java, c, php, etc. Pero después se me ocurrió que era mejor un **trigger** o **disparador**. Un **trigger** o **disparador** es como un **procedimiento almacenado** con esta diferencia: un trigger nunca puede ser llamado como ocurre con el procedimiento, sino que se ejecuta automáticamente cuando se produce un cambio (insert, update, delete) en una tabla. Es una especie de Action Listener digamos. Entonces podes utilizar el **trigger** para que al momento de **insertar** un registro con fecha inicio y fecha término que calcule el valor de las **horas trabajadas** y te lo inserte en otra tabla o en la misma. En mi caso elegí que lo inserte en la misma tabla, o sea que le agregué un campo llamado `tiempoDeServicio` de tipo `time`. Entonces mi tabla que llamé `servicio` quedó así: `idServicio (int autoincrement)`, `fechaInicio (datetime)`, `fechaTermino (datetime)`, `tiempoDeServicio (time)`. El **trigger** es de tipo `before insert`, **insert** por que se va a ejecutar cuando se produzca un insert en la tabla, y **before** por que se ejecutará **antes** de la inserción ya que primero tiene que hacer el cálculo de las horas trabajadas. En resumen, cuando se vaya a insertar un registro en la tabla `servicio`, un instante antes, el trigger ejecuta las instrucciones que le pusimos (calcular el tiempo entre `fechaInicio` y `fechaTermino` e insertarlo en `tiempoDeServicio`). Para mencionar algunas ventajas importantes sobre el uso de los triggers se podría decir que:

1. son más eficientes para el sistema ya que el código es procesado por el servidor en si mismo y de esa forma evita transferencia de datos entre el servidor y el cliente.
2. encapsulación: permite mayor seguridad ya que el cliente no tiene forma de ver las instrucciones que se ejecutan en el trigger.

Además por lo que estuve investigando también se utilizan mucho para controlar ingreso de datos (evitar datos erróneos), realizar respaldo de registros antes de actualizar un valor, y automatización del mantenimiento de la base de datos.
Ahora va el código para crear el trigger. Debes ejecutarlo por (única vez) tal cual está desde donde quieras, como ser en phpMyAdmin en la pestaña `sql`, o en workbench seleccionando todo el código y dándole al rayito.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger servicio_BI before insert on servicio for each row
begin

declare fechainiciovar datetime;
declare fechaterminovar datetime;
declare tiempo time default '00:00:00';
declare anio int;

    set fechainiciovar =new.fechainicio;
    set fechaterminovar =new.fechatermino;
    set anio =year(fechainiciovar);

 if 

  hour(fechainiciovar) not between 8 and 17
  or hour(fechaterminovar) not between 8 and 17
  or fechainiciovar > fechaterminovar

  or dayofweek(fechainiciovar) = 1 or dayofweek(fechainiciovar) = 7 
  or dayofyear(fechainiciovar) = 1
  or 

    ( dayofyear(fechainiciovar) = 359 and not(anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )

                                            or

    ( dayofyear(fechainiciovar) = 360 and (anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )

                                            or

    (  dayofyear(fechainiciovar) = 121 and not(anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )

                                            or

    ( dayofyear(fechainiciovar) = 122 and (anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )


  or dayofweek(fechaterminovar) = 1 or dayofweek(fechaterminovar) = 7 
  or dayofyear(fechaterminovar) = 1
  or 
    ( dayofyear(fechaterminovar) = 359 and not(anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )

                                            or

    ( dayofyear(fechaterminovar) = 360 and (anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )

                                            or

    (  dayofyear(fechaterminovar) = 121 and not(anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )

                                            or

    ( dayofyear(fechaterminovar) = 122 and (anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )


 then

    set tiempo =null;

 else

    while fechainiciovar < fechaterminovar do
       set anio =year(fechainiciovar);

       if hour(fechainiciovar) between 8 and 17

        and dayofweek(fechainiciovar) != 1 and dayofweek(fechainiciovar) != 7 
        and dayofyear(fechainiciovar) != 1 and (

        not( dayofyear(fechainiciovar) = 359 and not(anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )

                                               and

        not( dayofyear(fechainiciovar) = 360 and (anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )

                                               and

        not(  dayofyear(fechainiciovar) = 121 and not(anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )

                                               and

        not( dayofyear(fechainiciovar) = 122 and (anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0) )

                                               )

        then

         if timediff(fechaterminovar,fechainiciovar) > '00:59:59' then
            if timediff('18:00:00',time(fechainiciovar)) < '00:59:59' then
               set tiempo =addtime(tiempo,timediff('18:00:00',time(fechainiciovar)));
               set fechainiciovar = addtime(fechainiciovar,timediff('18:00:00',time(fechainiciovar)));
            else set tiempo =addtime(tiempo,'1:00:00');
               set fechainiciovar = adddate(fechainiciovar,interval 1 hour);
            end if;
         else set tiempo =addtime(tiempo,timediff(fechaterminovar,fechainiciovar));
            set fechainiciovar = adddate(fechainiciovar,interval 1 hour); 
         end if;
       else set fechainiciovar = adddate(fechainiciovar,interval 1 hour);
       end if;
    end while;
 end if;

 set new.tiempodeservicio =tiempo;

end;$$
delimiter ;
```

No voy a explicar todo el código por que es muy largo, pero resumidamente lo que hace es crear el trigger con el nombre `servicio_BI` (que por convención conviene seguir esa regla), `before insert` que ya lo expliqué, `on servicio` que indica la tabla donde se agregará el trigger, `for each row` que significa que se ejecutará "por cada reguistro" insertado. Luego viene el `begin`, todo lo que esté dentro del bloque `begin - end` son las instrucciones que se van a ejecutar. Fijate que al principio 
cuando asigno a la variable `fechainiciovar` y `fechaterminovar` hay un `new`, este `new` hace referencia al valor que todavía no fue insertado. Para los feriados usé la función `dayofyear()` la cuál te devuelve el día del año, entonces para el 1 de enero es sencillo, le decis: si `dayofyear(fechainiciovar) =1` entonces haceme esto.. Pero el problema es con las fechas que van a partir del **29 de febrero**, ya que el número de día cambia conforme al año si es **bisiesto**. Por ejemplo el 1 de mayo de este año fue el día del año número `121` pero el año que viene (bisiesto) va a ser el número `122`, entonces para resolver esto se me ocurrió decirle: ¿es igual a 122 cuando el año es bisiesto? y de paso saqué a la cancha la fórmula famosa de año bisiesto `anio % 4 =0 and anio % 100 !=0 or anio % 400 =0`. Después con un bucle `while` voy incrementando `fechainiciovar` y el contador sería `tiempo`, el cual incrementa solo cuando son días y horas hábiles. Fijate que le puse como feriados sábados y domingos, o sea `dayofweek(fechainiciovar) = 1 or dayofweek(fechainiciovar) = 7`, 1 de enero, 1 de mayo y 25 de diciembre, así que le podes agregar o quitar conforme a tus necesidades. La única limitación que tiene es que no admite que tanto `fechaInicio` 
como `fechaTermino` esté fuera del rango de `8:00:00 a 18:00:00`, o que sea feriado, por lo tanto si el usuario ingresa alguno de esos valores, `tiempo` va a ser `null`. Analiza bien todo el código y preguntame la parte que no entiendas.